# Plotting piecewise linear functions with gnuplot inaccurately

Tags: gnuplot

I have a problem when plotting a piecewise linear function h(x) = max(0, 1-|x|) (hat function) with gnuplot. My goal is to showcase the interpolation of a polynomial employing these hat functions as basis functions. Thus I need to shift and scale them to different grid points.

My code looks like this:

```
set key inside bottom right
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:6]
set grid xtics
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#0060ad' linetype 1 linewidth 2
set ytics 1
set xtics 2**(-3)
set key right top
s(x) = (3.0 * x - 1)
a0 = 2
a1 = -6
a2 = 5
a3 = 5
a4 = -5
a5 = 1
f(x) = a0 + a1*s(x) + a2*(s(x)**2) + a3*(s(x)**3) + a4*(s(x)**4) + a5*(s(x)**5)
max(x, y) = (x > y) ? x:y
h(x) = max(0, 1 - abs(x))
nodal(x, i)=h(2**(3)*x - i) * f(i * 2**(-3))

plot f(x) title "f(x)", nodal(x, 1)
```

The output however looks like this:
[image: Plot of the polynomial and one nodal basis function]

Obviously towards the point where the nodal basis function is not differentiable it fails to nicely plot the function, which looks bad. As I want to include this a thesis I have to submit, it is not something that I could include. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: `set samples 10000`

Comment: Thank you, solved the problem for me!